# Determining what process has bound a port (without listening) on Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, port, tcpip, sockets

If I want to find out what process is *listening* on what socket, I can use netstat/TCPview and will immediately see it. However, it is possible to bind to an address without listening. If this is done, it does not show up in netstat/TCPview, but does block the socket.

Python example:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('0.0.0.0',12345))
```

The port is now bound, and attempting to execute the same code in a second instance while the first is still running will result in an error. However, unless you actually start listening on that port using

```
s.listen(1)
```

the port does not show up in netstat/TCPview.

The question is:
**Is it possible to see what ports are *bound* (but not listening), and which process is binding them?**

The background of this is that I <s>have</s> had a [moving range of 1976 ports that cannot be bound](https://superuser.com/questions/556759/tcp-udp-ports-that-cannot-be-bound-permission-error-but-dont-show-up-in-nets), and I want to know what causes this. In the meantime, I determined through trial and error that Internet Connection Sharing was blocking those ports, but I am still curious about the answer to this question.

**Edit:** Due to popular request, here is the code I used to find those ports:

```
import time
import socket

for i in range(0,65536):
    try:
        print "Listening on port", i, '...', 
        serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        serversocket.bind(('0.0.0.0', i))
        serversocket.listen(5)
        #time.sleep(0.1)
        serversocket.close()
        print "ok"
    except:
        print "FAIL"
```

(you may want to pipe the output to grep and filter for FAIL only)

Comment: You can loop this script from 0 to 65535, log the ports it fails on and compare the result with netstat ports. The ones not listed in netstat should be what you are looking for. I don't know of any tool or technique that will show you what process is behind those ports, unless it is listening.

Comment: @Kedar: That is exactly what I did to find out which ports are affected.

Comment: @Lizz: Code posted.

Comment: could you post it as the answer? would be good to have as reference :)

Comment: @Lizz: It is not an answer to the question. It shows which ports are affected, but not what is occupying them.

Answer (score 6):

I had to do this exact thing today. Powershell can do it with `Get-NetTCPConnection`.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 53100

LocalAddress                        LocalPort RemoteAddress                       RemotePort State       AppliedSetting OwningProcess
------------                        --------- -------------                       ---------- -----       -------------- -------------
0.0.0.0                             53100     0.0.0.0                             0          Bound                      40120


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> get-process -PID 40120

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
   2133    1331    13884      30740  30,955.31  40120   1 HWMonitorPro
```

Answer (score 4):

In recent versions of netstat there is now a command line parameter -q that shows those sockets.

```
$ netstat -?

Displays protocol statistics and current TCP/IP network connections.

NETSTAT [-a] [-b] [-e] [-f] [-n] [-o] [-p proto] [-r] [-s] [-x] [-t] [interval]

  -a            Displays all connections and listening ports.
  -b            Displays the executable involved in creating...
  ...
  -p proto      Shows connections for the protocol specified...
  -q            Displays all connections, listening ports, and bound
                nonlistening TCP ports. Bound nonlistening ports may or may not
                be associated with an active connection.
  -r            Displays the routing table.
  ...
```

Example of use:

```
$ netstat -nq -p tcp

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:7              0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:9              0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:13             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  ...

 TCP    192.168.122.157:50059  54.213.66.195:443      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49676          0.0.0.0:0              BOUND
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49700          0.0.0.0:0              BOUND
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49704          0.0.0.0:0              BOUND
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49705          0.0.0.0:0              BOUND
  ...
```

It seems there is no public API for getting the sockets in that situation. See my [question in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605088/windows-api-for-enumerating-bound-but-unconnected-sockets).

Comment: I thought that should work for me too! Except it didn't! I just now discovered that if you use the `-b` option to find the process name then `-q` doesn't show BOUND sockets.

Answer (score 1):

you should use

> DWORD GetExtendedTcpTable (PVOID pTcpTable,PDWORD pdwSize, BOOL bOrder, ULONG ulAf,  TCP_TABLE_CLASS TableClass,ULONG Reserved );

with

TableClass value = TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL "or" TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_CONNECTIONS "or" TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_LISTENER

pTcpTable structure -> MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID

depending on the info you'd like to retrieve

EDIT:

TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL returns MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID structure that is an array of MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID structures where each `dwState` should have `MIB_TCP_STATE_CLOSED` when bound and not listening, this structure also offers `dwLocalAddr` and `dwLocalPort`

```
typedef struct _MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID {
  DWORD dwState;
  DWORD dwLocalAddr;
  DWORD dwLocalPort;
  DWORD dwRemoteAddr;
  DWORD dwRemotePort;
  DWORD dwOwningPid;
} MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID, *PMIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID;
```

Comment: This only lists sockets that are both bound and listening, but the question was specifically about sockets that are bound but not listening.

Comment: are you asserting or asking??? see the edit

Comment: When I run https://pastebin.com/vaHMVRQR I get nothing in the table for bind without listen (Win7)

Comment: The involved structures have particular alignments, you should not re-define them; you should reference the ones that are defined by MS. Also if you want to initially test a MS API Python is not the right tool; you should use C/C++ instead.

Comment: the code as displayed does not give information about sockets that are bound but unconnected; in recent versions of netstat there is now a command line parameter -q that shows those sockets